# Assign faces to UV map

Tags: mesh, modifiers, uv, objects

I have an object that I want to use a UV project modifier on, but I only want the modifier to affect certain parts of the mesh. I need a way to assign the areas I want moved to a second UV map. How can I approach this?

Comment: You can create a b&w image in order to create a mask that will separate a part from the other if you plug it into the factor of a Mix Shader or of a MixColor, and you can create another UV Map and use an Input > UV Map node, but maybe give some details about the object etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mask between your UV-projected texture and another, based on a separate UV map, in any way you like. It could be any float-attribute on the mesh, set via a vertex-group, or perhaps using Geometry Nodes...

Here, it's a B/W mask painted into an image: 'UV Mask', as mapped by the UV map: 'Not Projected'.

The 'Not Projected' UV also maps a *Brick* texture. The colored circles are mapped using the 'Projected' UV map, which is generated by a *UV Project* modifer.

[image]

So the maps are independent:

[image]